# Beginner - While Loop sum all user inputs under 50 - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

I am still a beginner on Javascript and I have a question.

I would like to sum all user inputs under 50 if written 0 to stop the program and display their amount

**By example:**

First Number 5, Second number 3, Third Number 55, Fourth Number 0. (The program will print 8)

```
var userInput = parseInt(prompt('Write Number'));


while(userInput!=0) {
    var userInput = parseInt(prompt('Try Again!'));
    if(userInput < 50){
        var sum = userInput + userInput;
    }
    document.write(sum + '<br>');

}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do this:

```js
var input = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));
var output = 0;

while (input > 0) {
  if (!(input > 50)) {
    output += input;
  }
  input = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));
}

document.write("The sum of all the numbers lower than 50 was " + output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The sum of all the numbers lower than 50 was NaN

Comment: @F.Rahamim I've fixed it now, any better?

Comment: @F.Rahamim No problem whatsoever

Answer (score 3):

loop and add previous value if condition match :

```js
var inputData = Number(prompt("Enter the input number"));
var finalOutput=0;

while (inputData > 0) {
    if (!(inputData > 50)) {
        finalOutput += inputData;
    }
    inputData = Number(prompt("Enter the input number"));
}

document.write("SUM is : " + finalOutput);
```

Comment: loop and increase if conditon meeets